Why Not Put the useState Hook in an If-Statement?
Intuitively it makes sense to me why, but I'm looking for an in-depth explanation of how React is compiled that would cause a side-effect with something like this.
const Header = () => {
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
   if(counter > 3) {
      const [subtext, setSubtext] = useState("Secret message unlocked.");
   }
   const [headertext, setHeadertext] = useState("Hello World!");
   
   const click = () => {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
   }

   return {
      <div>
         <h1>{headertext}</h1>
         <h2>{subtext}<h2>
         <button onClick={click}>Click Me!</button>
      </div>
   }
}


Because you cannot conditionally call React hooks. See React's Rules of Hooks for explanation.

Note that in this case subtext shouldn't be state at all, but just const subtext = counter > 3 ? 'Secret message unlocked.' : null;.

It is because of how react treats hooks. All hooks have an order to associate states and references with the correct component. If a hook is called conditionally or inside a loop, the order of hook calls can change between re-renderings breaking internal React logic to handle states.
In your code, for example, you have 3 hooks and one of them is inside an if statement, if that statement is not true then you will have 2 hooks but react will try look for 3 and will break.
